# Appending scaled circles to a multi-line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, graph

I have followed an example from here https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/4db972df5d7efc7d611255d1cc6f3c4f to create a similar graph. However, I have one additional column of data that I need to use to create circles that match the color of the line where the radius will be some scaled value of that column entry. So, col 3 has values like 873, 15, 1000, 1563, etc. I have tried to do something like

```
svg.selectAll('circle').data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close) })
    .attr("r", '5')
    .attr("fill", "red");
```

right below the point we add the path (right after adding the value line path in the link), however, obviously this only enters circles for one line. I have to add them for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need two circles' selections, one for `open` and another for `close`:

```
svg.selectAll(null).data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close) })
    .attr("r", '5')
    .attr("fill", "steelblue");

svg.selectAll(null).data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.open) })
    .attr("r", '5')
    .attr("fill", "red");
```

Here is the resulting code: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/4179c63daf38d85a266fb11f8e8e4c17/3786e4a0594e45e6e9a41df84bae4c6a43a86c6f